# which model for ordinal scaled dependent variable

Tags: data-mining

I want to use several models to find a relation btw. life satisfaction and several independent variables like children, unemployment, marriage and so on.

My dependent var has an ordinal scale [1:10] and the independent vars have nominal and ordinal scales but no metric ones.

I would set up an ordered model like an ordered probit, but I do not know what else I could use. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: You might want to read about ridit https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridit_scoring

Comment: That is something I am looking for. Are there any other ideas?